# MySQL TRIGGER weird behavior

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi guys I have the following code at some point of my trigger. (AFTER INSERT TRIGGER)

```
DECLARE Interv int;
```

At some point i use the following code:

```
SELECT myfield FROM TABLE WHERE interv=new.interv
```

But apparently the mysql confuses the value of two variables `(NEW.INTERV AND INTERV)` and don´t returns me the correct query's value.

But, if i use `DECLARE Interv_Value int` instead `DECLARE Interv int` the `SELECT` in question works fine.

Any ideas? I'm using MySQL 5.1.68.

Comment: does your table actually have an `interv` field? If so, then no wonder mysql is getting confused. if you're naming variables the same as table fields, then actual fields will take priority over a variable of the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is confusing about this?

When you have the query:

```
SELECT myfield
FROM TABLE
WHERE interv = new.interv;
```

Then MySQL has to figure out where all unqualified names come from.  It has some rules.  In this case:

```
- First look at the columns in the `FROM` clause.
- Then it look in the environment
```

(These are actually scoping rules and also involve subqueries.)  So, your query is interpreted as:

```
SELECT myfield
FROM TABLE
WHERE table.interv = new.interv;
```

As a general rule, write your queries using table aliases to specify where columns come from.  So the above query could be written as:

```
SELECT myfield
FROM TABLE t
WHERE t.interv = new.interv;
```

Although you don't really want this version.

If you want to use variables, use user-defined variables with an `@` or give the variables names that are unlikely to conflict with column names (I use `v_` prefixes for this).